# Practices on materialising queryables if ever the result is null

Tags: c#, linq

From my application i have codes like this:

`student entry = (from stud in emp.students where stud.id == st.id select stud).First();`

But if it's `null` then my application will crash.

My current methods as of now is to enclose them with a `try block` so it won't crash like:

```
try
{
next = emp.calendar.Where(x => x.term == "first" && x.schoolyear == year).First();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

or do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<calendar> cld = null;
//do stuff

cld = (from cd in emp.calendar where cd.regenroll >= nw && nw <= cd.regend select cd);
int count = cld.Count();

if (cls > 0)

//materialise

}
```

What are the good practices on checking if it's null or not before processing? assuming that it may or may not return a row.

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault,not First

Comment: ohhhhhhh i see, alright. So it will be null if no rows are returned?

Comment: Yes. `First`, `Single` etc have equivalent `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault` methods that will return null if nothing is returned

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First().` it will guard against the null exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
next = emp.calendar.Where(x => x.term == "first" && x.schoolyear == year).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that you need to use [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) when you know that the sequence has minimum one element. You will get an exception *like you are getting* when there are no elements present. And you need to use [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) when you have to check if the element exists like in your case. It will  either return null or the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of .First()

```
student entry = (from stud in emp.students 
                 where stud.id == st.id 
                 select stud
                ).FirstOrDefault();

if (entry == null)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.DefaultIfEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and optionally specify a default value to use in the empty case.

```
emp.calendar.Where(x => x.term == "first" && x.schoolyear == year).DefaultIfEmpty(/*optional default here*/).First();
```

Example without default value specified (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
class Pet
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public static void DefaultIfEmptyEx1()
        {
            List<Pet> pets =
                new List<Pet>{ new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                               new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                               new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

            foreach (Pet pet in pets.DefaultIfEmpty())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pet.Name);
            }
        }
```

Example with default value specified (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
class Pet
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Age { get; set; }
            }

            public static void DefaultIfEmptyEx2()
            {
                Pet defaultPet = new Pet { Name = "Default Pet", Age = 0 };


                List<Pet> pets1 =
                    new List<Pet>{ new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

                foreach (Pet pet in pets1.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPet))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", pet.Name);
                }

                List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet>();

                foreach (Pet pet in pets2.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPet))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nName: {0}", pet.Name);
                }
            }
```